# WKWebView video pausing not working for all the websites

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, video, html5-video

I am loading some website which contains some videos. I am using WKWebView for loading these videos. I need to stop the videos from autoplay when loading the pages, so I added the following java script code to pause the video.

```
NSString *script = @"var videos = document.querySelectorAll(\"video\"); for (var i = videos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { videos[i].pause(); };";
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Java script result = %@",result);
}];
```

I can able to pause the video in most of the websites that I am listing like CNN, Youtube etc. But it is not working for some websites. Example :

TheGlobe&Mail   - http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/news-video/

BBC             - http://www.bbc.com/news/video_and_audio

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a property in iOS 9.0 WKWebView called 
      requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback
If you set this to true, then you autoplay should be turned off

If you are using < iOS 9.0, set the property 
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction
to true to turn off autoplay.

I didnt yet try this on the websites you mentioned. Will update my answer once I do

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked long time ago but since there is no answer I'm going to answer this for everyone else who is seeking for the approach:

This is my code:

```
NSString *script = @"var videos = document.getElementsByTagName(\"video\");  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) { videos.item(i).pause(); };";
[self.webView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

```
webview.evaluateJavaScript("var videos = document.getElementsByTagName(\"video\");  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) { videos.item(i).pause(); };")
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/users/2640210/the-mach-system answer